# Find Particular integral of $(D^2+a^2)y=\sin ax$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My approach:

$PI=\frac{1}{D^2+a^2}(\sin ax)$.

Knowing that $\frac{1}{D}(e^x)=xe^x$ and $\sin ax= \frac{e^{iax}-e^{-iax}}{2i}$. I tried solving this.

Here is where I face difficulty,
$$ \frac{1}{2i(D^2+a^2)}(e^{iax}) = e^{iax}\frac{1}{2i((D+ia)^2+a^2)}(1) = e^{iax}\frac{1}{2iD(D+2ai)}(1)= e^{iax}\frac{1}{-4a}(1+\frac{D}{2ai})^{-1}(x) = e^{iax}\frac{1}{-4a}(x-\frac{1}{2ai})$$

In this process, I have operated first with $D$ and then with $(D+2ai)$.
The correct value for this $\frac{xe^{iax}}{-4a}$ which can only be obtained when I operated first with $(D+2ai)$ and then with $D$.

So, is there any precedence rule here because I feel that the order I operate in should not affect the answer. So what is it that I am missing here? Is there any rule of thumb here to remember?

**P.S.** $e^{-iax}$ term can be computed similarly and combined at the end. That's not the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of particular solution it's better to use the resonant response formula:
$$y_p=\dfrac {e^{iax}}{P(ia)} \text { for } P(ia) \ne 0 $$
Here $P(ia)$ equal zero take the derivative:
$$y_p=\Im \dfrac {xe^{iax}}{P'(ia)} $$
$$y_p=-\Im \dfrac {ix}{2a}e^{iax}$$
$$y_p=-\Im \dfrac {ix}{2a}(\cos (ax)+i \sin (ax))$$
Finally:
$$\boxed {y_p=-\dfrac {x}{2a}\cos (ax)}$$
And the complete solution is:
$$y(x)=y_h(x)+y_p(x)$$
$$y(x)=c_1 \cos (ax)+c_2 \sin (ax)-\dfrac {x}{2a}\cos (ax)$$

---

Using OP's method
$$y_p=\dfrac {1}{2i}\dfrac 1 {D^2+a^2}e^{iax}$$
$$2iy_p=e^{iax}\dfrac 1 {(D+ia)^2+a^2}e^0$$
$$2iy_p=e^{iax}\dfrac 1 {D^2+2iaD}e^0$$
$$2iy_p=e^{iax}\dfrac 1 {D(D+2ia)}e^0$$
$$2iy_p=e^{iax}\dfrac 1 {D2ia}e^0$$
$$-4y_p=e^{iax}\dfrac 1 {D}e^0$$
$$-4y_p=e^{iax}x$$
Finally:
$$y_p=-\dfrac {xe^{iax}}{4}$$
And this is correct too...

Comment: This is the third different answer.

Comment: It agrees with WA https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%2Ba%5E2y%3Dsin%28ax%29  @Alearner

Comment: I didn't say,,, it's wrong,,, it's the another possibility.

Comment: Also,,there may be!!

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact, $\frac{\sin(ax)}{f(D^2)}=\frac{\sin(ax)}{f(-a^{2})}$ provided $f(-a^{2})\neq 0 $ ,
If , $f(-a^{2})= 0 $(as ,in this case) , then $\frac{\sin(ax)}{f(D^2)}=\frac{x\sin(ax)}{f'(-a^2)}$ , here , $f'=\frac{d}{dD}$.

So,$\frac{\sin(ax)}{D^{2}+a^{2}}=\frac{x\sin(ax)}{2D} $ as, $f(-a^{2})= 0 $ ,

Now, as there is no term containing $D^{2}$ in $f(D)$, we can't go again for computation.
So, $\frac{x\sin(ax)}{2D}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{-xcos(ax)}{a}+\frac{sin(ax)}{a^2})$

**Following your process**,
Start with,
$$ \frac{1}{(D^2+a^2)}(e^{iax}) $$
$$= e^{iax}\frac{1}{((D+ia)^2+a^2)}(1) $$
$$= e^{iax}\frac{1}{(2ai)D(1+\frac{D}{2ai})}(1) $$
$$= e^{iax}\frac{1}{(2ai)}(\frac{1}{D}-\frac{1}{2ai}+\frac{D}{(2ai)^2}-\frac{D^{2}}{(2ai)^3}+\cdot\cdot\cdot)(1) $$
$$= e^{iax}\frac{1}{2ai}(x-\frac{1}{2ai})$$
$$=e^{iax} (\frac{-xi}{2a}+\frac{1}{4a^2})$$
$$=cos(ax)\frac{1}{4a^2}+sin(ax)\frac{x}{2a}+i(sin(ax)\frac{1}{4a^2}-cos(ax)\frac{x}{2a})$$

In this case , P.I.$$=sin(ax)\frac{1}{4a^2}-cos(ax)\frac{x}{2a}$$,the answer is little different from the answer derived from the first method,, as we know **P.I.** is not unique.

Comment: How did you arrive at conclusion $ \frac{\sin ax}{f(D^2)}=\frac{x \sin ax}{f'(-a^2)} $?

Comment: Also, $\frac{\sin ax}{D^2+a^2} = \frac{-x \cos ax}{2a}$

Comment: This is a rule for finding P.I..

Comment: Part of your solution is absorbed by the homogeneous solution of the differential equation I mean the $\sin (ax)$ part. So that you can simplify a little bit your particular solution.

Answer (score 0):

On going through text, I realized that there is in fact a precedence order here.

In a case where $\frac{1}{D(D+a)}(e^x)$.

First the $(D+a)$ or the non-vanishing factor is operated upon and at last when there are no non-vanishing factors left, the vanishing factor is operated upon. Same is the case for any function other than $e^x$.

As is evident, the reason for this is that the vanishing factor unnecessarily increases the degree thereby adding more terms which would not have come otherwise.